# GDB hardware watchpoint very slow - why?

Tags: gdb, watchpoint

On a large C application, I have set a hardware watchpoint on a memory address as follows:

```
(gdb) watch *0x12F5D58
Hardware watchpoint 3: *0x12F5D58
```

As you can see, it's a hardware watchpoint, not software, which would explain the slowness.

Now the application running time under debugger has changed from less than ten seconds to one hour and counting. The watchpoint has triggered three times so far, the first time after 15 minutes when the memory page containing the address was made readable by `sbrk`. Surely during those 15 minutes the watchpoint should have been efficient since the memory page was inaccessible? And that still does not explain, why it's so slow afterwards.

The platform is x86_64 and the GDB versions are Ubuntu 9.10 package:

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0-ubuntu
[...]
```

and stock GDB 7.1 built from sources:

```
$ gdb-7.1 --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas as what might be the cause or how to fix/work around it.

EDIT: removed cast

EDIT: gdb 7.1

Comment: Is it always slow when running under the debugger, or only when you have a watchpoint set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've actually had trouble with hardware watchpoints in GDB 7.x.x., which is not acceptable since watchpoints are a necessity in my job.

On advice from a co-worker, I downloaded the source for 6.7.1 and built it locally.  Watchpoints work much better now.

Might be worth a try.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this out.

Comment: GDB 6.7.1 is missing a feature where one can use watchpoints on memory address that is inaccessible at the watchpoint setup time. It is possible to enable it at the right time, but this will be more involved, I will try later. I have also tried just released GDB 7.1, same problem as with 7.0.

Comment: with conditional breakpoints and breakpoint commands you might be able to work around that without too much trouble.

Answer (score 10):

I discovered that watching a large character buffer was very slow, whereas watching a character in that buffer was very fast.

e.g.

```
static char buf[1024];
static char* buf_address = &buf;
```

`watch buf_address` - excruciatingly slow.

`watch *buf_address` - very fast.

Answer (score 5):

It's most likely because you're casting it each time.  Try this:

```
(gdb) watch *0x12F5D58
```

---

Another option is that you have too many hardware watchpoints set, so gdb is forced to use software watchpoints.  Try checking how many watchpoints you have using:

```
(gdb) info break
```

and see if you can disable some watchpoints.

Comment: Can gdb really dereference an integer literal, without needing to know what type to dereference as? That's not a valid C expression, at least ...

Comment: Yes, it can. I do it all the time.

Comment: To my surprise (I thought GDB only accepts C expressions) "watch *0x12F5DF8" works, but is as slow as the previous version.

Comment: Re. another option, I don't have too many of *points, I am testng with two (disabled) breakpoints and a single watchpoint.

Comment: what happens if you *delete* the breakpoints instead of *disabling* them?

Comment: With just the watchpoint and everything else deleted, performance still is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas (and for *0xABCDABCD syntax)

Comment: What's your platform? Maybe GDB is reporting it's using a hardware watchpoint but falls back to software.

Comment: @Joseph: judging from the fact that he's using Ubuntu, I naturally assumed he was on x86.

Comment: x86_64. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: By the way, you can probably also dereference constants in C as well, if you know where your data is located.

Answer (score 1):

On x86 you have the following limitation: all your watchpoints can cover no more than four memory addresses, each address of memory can watch for one memory word - this is because hardware watchpoints (the fast ones) use the processors debug registers, an you have four of them, therefore four locations to watch for.

Comment: He already said he only had a single watchpoint, see the fourth comment to Nathan's answer.